# C - Comput Bitwise OR using only & and ~

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

I'm trying to compute bitwise | only using & and ~.

```
   int main() {

   int num1 = 3;
   int num2 = 6;

   printf("%d\n",num1|num2); 

   num1 = ~num1;
   num2 = ~num2;

   printf("d\n",num1);
   printf("d\n",num2);

   int num3 = num1 & num2;    

   printf("%d\n",num3); 

}
```

And here is the output:

```
7
d
d
-8
```

I'm trying to figure out why `~num1` is outputting `d`?

Comment: you're missing the `%` in those `printfs`

Comment: Because you forgot the `%` specifier so the plain character is printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
   printf("d\n",num1);
   printf("d\n",num2);
```

with

```
   printf("%d\n",num1);
   printf("%d\n",num2);
```